# Two functions that can't be applied in different order to arrive at same result

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Here's my puzzle:

> Write two unary functions `f`, `g` and provide an input `x` so that only the combination `f(g(x))` will yield the result `y` but no other combination of them does - even if applied multiple times in any order.

The functions should use standard arithmetic operations, the numbers should be small integers, too keep it simple (so that the solution `y = f(g(x))` is obvious to everyone). If that is not possible, feel free to use more advanced operations or rational numbers.

I am still trying to solve it myself. I just made it up<sup>[1]</sup>, I don't think it's a well-known problem.

I have tried some simple additions and multiplications, but it proved unexpectedly hard. Maybe I just don't know the right mathematical tool or can't see the pattern. I thought about prime numbers, but they don't really seem to help here. Some (counter)examples:

- `1`, `*3`, `*5` - but also `1 *5 *3 = 15`
- `0`, `+3`, `*5` - but also `0 *5 +3 *5 = 15`
- `1`, `+3`, `*5` - but also `1 *5 +3 +3 +3 +3 +3 = 20`
- `1`, `*5`, `+2` - but also `1 +2 +2 +2 = 7`
- `1`, `+3`, `/2` - but also `1 +3 +3 +3 /2 +3 /2 /2 = 2`
- `2`, `+3`, `^2` - but also `2 ^2 ^2 +3 +3 +3 = 25`

<sub>1: If you're curious, I am trying to write a test for a computer program that implements function composition.</sub>

Comment: If you are allowed to apply some index $j$ in how the functions are composed, you could use $f(x) = k^j\cdot x$ -- assuming that $k^j$ is greater than any input $x$. For binary $x$, we can use $f(x) = 2^j\cdot x$ to get a unique representation.

Comment: @CarlLöndahl: no indices. You don't know how often, at which point in the sequence, or whether at all the function is used. Notice you can also choose `x`, it doesn't need to work on any input.

Comment: If you use $f(x)=x+1$, $g(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$, with the starting value of $1$, then every positive rational number is the result of exactly one sequence of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @f'' Please post that as an answer!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about the following for a single operator version:

> Let $f(x)=x/2$, let $g(x)=x-3$, and let $x=13$, with $y=5$.

If we perform $f(g(x))$, we get $y$. If we perform $f$ before $g$, we will get a non-integer (and applying $f$ or $g$ after this will not help). If we perform $g$ more than once, then the resulting value is too low to apply $f$ to reach $y$.  We cannot apply $g$ by itself any number of times to reach $y$.  Once we reach $y$, using either function will make the result too low to return to $y$ (since both functions are strictly decreasing).

Comment: The reverse, `5`, `*2` and `+3` seems to be even simpler

Comment: @Bergi I originally avoided functions of the form `*n` and `+m` given the number of counterexamples that contained them; it seems I came full circle.  I suppose the strictly increasing version is simpler, although the strictly decreasing version was easier to see the proof in my head before writing down.

Comment: Wouldn't $f(g(g(16))$ generate $5$?  I guess that doesn't use $13$ as input.

Answer (score 6):

OK, I figured out one solution. Binary, as mentioned by Carl Löndahl in the comments, should've been obvious. It hit me though when I looked at a string concatenation.

> Start with `1`, use `λx → x⋅2+0` and `λx → x⋅2+1` as functions. Or bitshift and xor, if you want.

I'm still wondering though whether there is a solution using a single operator per function.

Answer (score 1):

$f(n) = p^n, g(n) = q^n$ such that $\gcd(p, q) = 1, p, q \in \mathbb Z^+.$

This works for all positive $n$. Mind you, the numbers you get will be pretty big. An integer power of $p$ cannot be equal to an integer power of $q$, so there is no $h(n) \in \{\textrm{compositions of }f, g\}$ such that $(f\circ h)(n) = (g \circ h)(n)$.

Comment: …`p, q > 1` :-)

Comment: Right, I seem to have backspaced that portion...